# In C under what circumstances would the function realloc return Null?

Tags: c++, c, realloc

Realloc is used to resize a previously allocated memory block? Under what circumstances would this function call return a null value?

Comment: Did you try, google it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `realloc` function can't get more memory to expand the block to the size you asked for. This is either because there is literally no memory available, or the virtual space is exhausted (e.g. a 32-bit application on a 64-bit machine with 16GB of RAM still can't use more than 4GB in the process space).

It MAY also return NULL if the new size is 0.

Note that in Linux (and possibly other OS's), when running on a system with limited memory (that is, the memory size is smaller than the virtual memory size), you are more likely to have your process killed by OOM-killer than receive a NULL pointer.

Comment: or memory fragmentation

Answer (score 0):

CLICK [1]: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/?kw=realloc

If the function fails to allocate the requested block of memory, a null pointer is returned, and the memory block pointed to by argument ptr is not deallocated (it is still valid, and with its contents unchanged).

Comment: I wouldn't really recommend this reference.

Comment: The question was "under what circumstances" could if fail, not how failure is indicated and handled.